# how to do routing basis on drop down down value?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes, tags

I am trying to do routing basis on drop down value and also I want to append my new html into existing html. E.g
I have a component main.ts and main.html and a second component submain.ts and submain.html.
In my main.ts, I have a list -

```
routes = [
    {
      value: 'process1',
      display: 'Process1'
    },
    {
      value: 'process2',
      display: 'process2'
    }
  ]
 onActivate(event) {
    console.log("insde activate ")
    if (event instanceof Test2Component) {
      this.currentRoute = 'react';
    } 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentRoute = '';
  }
  routeTo(e) {
    console.log('something change')
    this.router.navigate(['/' + e]);
  }
```

In my main.html:

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="currentRoute" (change)="routeTo(currentRoute)">
    <option *ngFor="let r of routes" [ngValue]="r.value">{{r.display}}</option>
  </select>
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

Current url is main but i want to change the url to:

```
main/process1                         // if process1 selected...    
main/process2                         // if process2 selected...
```

And to drop down to be there(main.html) along with my submain.html content for that I am using router-outlet.
However, whenever I select any value, its says "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'process1'". I believe the issue is with the routing. I have added following in my app.routing-modules.ts:

```
{path:'main',component:MainComponent,pathMatch:'full'}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to define the child routes, possibly as one child route with a route parameter

Comment: Hi Moxxi, i tried that as well. but didn't work. {path:'main',component:MainComponent,pathMatch:'full', children:[
  {path:'main/process1',component:SubMainComponent}

]},

Comment: you don't need to use main again in path. Please refer for example: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/child_routes